# how to use JS or CSS to display 50 images one by one with touch swipe

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm new here.
There is web app project to show different images (I guess more than 50 images) by touch swiping the screen.
You can imagine that this is like playing cartoon. When I swipe the screen, the images will be displayed one after another.
The size of each image is 1-2MB.

Here is my code. imgs is array of images.

```
box1.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){  
    var i = 0;
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]; 
    var dist = Math.abs(parseInt(touchobj.clientX) - startx );
    var X = Math.floor(dist/5) ;    

    for(;i<X;i++) {
      if (i < 40)  { 
       box1.innerHTML = "<img src=" + imgs[i] + " style='width:100%' >";
      } else {
       box1.innerHTML = "<img src=" + imgs[50] + " style='width:100%' >";
      }
    }

    e.preventDefault();
}, false)
```

Comment: What's the problem? Be specific.

Comment: problem is that each image isn't loaded smoothly(too slow) .  I want to improve the performance.

Comment: That's to be expected with 50MB+ of images on one slider. Lazy loading might help.BTW I think your conditional should be `if (i < 50) {...`

Answer (score 0):

I think when you swipe between images you just want to see an overview of the images not the full resolution 1-2 Mb version, so you can use [load image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) library to scale images and provide a way to select one of the images to see it with full resolution.

tip: you could use Math.min to get rid of the if/else part

```
for(;i<X;i++) {
   box1.innerHTML = "<img src=" + imgs[Math.min(i, 50)] + " style='width:100%' >";
}
```

Comment: Actually , I need full resolution 1-2 MB version images. Cause it's a app to show different shade of color. Anyway, thanks for your comments

Comment: Do you have other solution to do this? I mean another totally different idea.Thanks for advance.